# Why won't my app develop an authenticode reputation

Tags: certificate, code-signing, authenticode

We have now purchased two Code Signing certificates that are supposed to work with Authenticode for downloads.  We used Comodo for our source and I am certain we have the correct type of certificate.

We set up Installshield to sign the setup package and followed all the directions I know of.  After more than a full year we still get treated as if our code is unknown and our users have to override the security objections and install.

What do we have to do to finally get this thing working?  I have searched the net and we are doing everything I can find yet it is as if our code is unsigned.

How do we get a reputation?  How many downloads are needed?  Our app is downloaded hundreds but not thousands of times per year approximately, does that matter?

Please advise, we are incredibly frustrated as are our users.